# Dask shared futures with Channels and memory usage

Tags: python, distributed, dask

I'm playing with the dask functionality described here "[Shared Futures With Channels](https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channels.html)".

As explained in the document i managed to submit futures and add them to the channel. Then from another client I manage to run through the future and to get the result from them.

In my use case, it's possible to have a lot of futures loaded to the channel.
When i look at the scheduler i see that the memory usage  growth even and stay high even after that i get the result.

Is there a way to unload the futures from a channel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of January 2017 there is no mechanism to clear out specific futures from a channel, though this could possibly be added.  You might want to raise an issue [here](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/new).

You might also consider creating a channel with a maximum length using the `maxlen=` parameter

```
chan = Channel('my-channel', maxlen=100)
```

You will need to do this the first time you create the channel.

Comment: There's no way to clear out specific futures. Is there a way to clear a channel ?

Comment: Not at the moment, no.  You could raise an issue though.

Comment: Thx for your answers i'll raise an isssue for that and i will try to handle my use case with public datasets.